# Delete colums from csv results wrong

Tags: csv, python-2.7

Trying to delete all columns from a csv file except 'fruit'.

script I modified from another post on this site

```
import csv
with open("C:\\Test\\source.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader(source)
    with open("C:\\Test\\result.csv","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer(result)
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow(r[1])
```

source.csv

```
ID,fruit,number,location  
0,apple,2,3  
1,banana,1,1  
2,pear,2,3  
3,grape,0,1
```

results I got:

```
f,r,u,i,t  
a,p,p,l,e  
b,a,n,a,n,a  
p,e,a,r  
g,r,a,p,e
```

desired results

```
fruit  
apple  
banana  
pear  
grape
```

Any ideas as to how to get rid of the commas? I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `writerow()` a list:

```
wtr.writerow([r[1]])
```

`writerow()` expects a *sequence*, something ordered. Lists are sequences, but so are strings; strings can be indexed, iterated over, etc. By passing in just `r[1]` you give `.writerow()` a sequence of individual characters, each written as a separate column.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple. Still trying to get my head around the why r[1] outputs commas and the [r[1]] does not. Any links you can point me to that goes into greater details on this concept? Can't truly learn if I don't understand.

Comment: @user12059: Type `list('somestring')` in the python interpreter. Or `'somestring[0]'`.